# How to remove unwanted commas using Jinja2

Tags: jinja2

How do I make this...

```
, ,apple,orange, , , ,mango, ,
```

into...

```
apple,orange,mango
```

using Jinja2?

I have tried this...

```
{% set fruits = ', ,apple,orange, , , ,mango, , ' %}

{% set fruits_array = fruits.split(',') %}

{% for fruit in fruits_array %}
  {%- if fruit|trim != '' -%}
    {{- fruit|trim -}}
    {{ "," if not loop.last }}
  {%- endif -%}
{% endfor %}
```

there is always a trailing comma in the result.

Comment: Can't you just add a test of that last character and remove it? I don't know that language, but it must have functions to take the substring except its last char...

Answer (score 3):

I manage to solve this using this...

```
{% for fruit in fruits_array if fruit|trim != '' %}
  {{- fruit|trim -}}
  {{ "," if not loop.last }}
{% endfor %}
```